# Android game development

Tags: android, google-play-games, 2d-games

I want start develop games on Android.
I'm yet an android app developer but I never develop a game.
Can you help me for understand how start. It is better to use an external development suite like Unity 3d or is possibile to develop games just with Android Studio and SDK like the normal apps?
The game I want to develop is simple, just a sprite and a backgroud. The sprite can move and jump.

Thank you

Comment: Use SurfaceView in XML and Draw image on using Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using libgdx for android game development even more so if you are planning to transfer your game to ios too in the future. You can find great tutorials on the internet for libgdx. If I was you i'd check out udacity's libgdx tutorial. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check the LibGdx on oficial page. People can do awesome thinks with this library. Do you know Ingress? This game was make in LibGDX

Check the official page

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

also look at projects

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/gallery.html

you have docs:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/

and the rich forum. Enjoy

Comment: Thank you, but in this way I develop directly with libgdx and it create my apk? And if I want to use native android hardware like camera, sensors etc..??

Comment: U use the normal java, android java and java libgdx so u can create all what u want

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what about sprite design etc?? Where I make it?